# Notifying a certain third party via syslog for a particular PostgreSQL entry

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to send some notifications to an external monitoring server via syslog or snmp or another delivery method when a certain table receives a record that is out of threshold?

For example, let's say I have this metrics table with the following columns:

```
Timestamp          || Metric_Name || Value
2020/10/23 15:01      A              23
2020/10/23 15:02      B              50
2020/10/23 15:03      A              67
2020/10/23 15:03      B              90
```

And I want a way to get notification if I receive a value over 50 for metric A.

Can anyone propose a utility or psql native way to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: Does it need to be a "push" notification or could the monitoring server be the one initiating the connection?

Comment: Ideally, push.. Can something be done via triggers? Something after the INSERT maybe?

Comment: Yes, it'll probably involve a trigger, then either logging to postgres' log file if that is configured as expected, or using an [extension such as `plsh`](https://github.com/petere/plsh) to execute os commands (see eg. [here](https://github.com/petere/plsh) or [there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/128229/188406))

Comment: Do you think I can write a record to a local log file for each row that exceeds my custom threshold?